# Different behavior with torch.mean(data, 0) and torch.mean(data) for vector

Tags: python, pytorch, mean, mnist

I was surprised to find different behavior with torch.mean(data, 0) and torch.mean(data), where "data" — is 1D-tensor (vector, not a matrix or something else):

```
from torchvision import datasets
import torch

path = './MNIST_data'

data = datasets.MNIST(path, train=True, download=True).train_data.view(-1).float()

print(torch.mean(data))
print(torch.mean(data, 0))
```

Results after execution:

```
tensor(33.3184)
tensor(33.4961)
```

Could anyone suppose what is going on? I assumed that the results should be the same.

Comment: Did you look at the actual data? Could you replicate this with other (simple synthetic) data?

Comment: @THN after reshaping MNIST by `view(-1)` I got a list of 0-to-255 numbers. Furthermore, if we try to calculate mean by `numpy.mean(data)` and `numpy.mean(data, axis=0)` (not by `torch.mean`) we will got the identical results.

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue on github, sounds like a bug to me. May related to optimization in low precision floating-point calculation, not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

An Example should help you clear your doubt.

Lets say we have `data = torch.Tensor([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])`

Now When you perform `torch.mean(data)`,It will sum all the elements in the data tensor and divide that by the number of elements in that tensor,Giving you a result of `2.5`

As for your operation of `torch.mean(data, 0)` This will perform mean along the horizontal direction,which means it will take the first element of row one which is 1 and take the first element of row 2 which is 2,sum them up and divide by 2.It helps to visualize the data array this way

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The final result will be tensor of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` if you know how we ended up getting this tensor, You've understood the difference.

Hope that clears it, Let me know if you have questions

Comment: In my example, data is 1D-tensor, not a matrix like in your answer, that is vector: `data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. It was reshaped by `view(-1)`. It has one axis and `torch.mean(data)` must be equal to `torch.mean(data, 0)`. And why I got different results for `torch.mean(data)` and `torch.mean(data, 0)` in my case?